# Laravel Class 'App\Exceptions\Controller' not found

Tags: laravel-5

My question is that when I call route (post method) in group and localizationredirect is set, It return **Class 'App\Exceptions\Controller' not found** but when I call it outside the group it access successfully.

Please let me know that Is that possible to call the route (post method) in group.

Not working: http://localhost/lovebnb/**en**/join/upload-photo/33

Working: http://localhost/lovebnb/join/upload-photo/33

Comment: are you using [Laravel Localisation Package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) if so, please specify as 'localisationredirect' as far as i am aware is not bundled in Laravel.

Comment: Yes I am using this. But when I call this in group gives error and outside this run.